# How to create in-memory pdf file and send as an email attachement using groovy

Tags: pdf, groovy, in-memory

I'm facing issue with generating pdf in-memory and sending as an email attachment, I wrote below code to convert base 64 encode to decode and generate the pdf file in local disk, due to space constraints I don't want to store in local instead I want to keep in-memory. How can I achieve this in groovy?

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64


        String content = "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"
        byte[] pdfFileData = Base64.decodeBase64(content.getBytes())
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("test.pdf"), pdfFileData)
```

Comment: it's already in memory at line `byte[] pdfFileData = ...`

Comment: Since you already have it in memory, we can assume your problem is with sending the mail.  Please add the code, that shows the problem with sending the mail or e.g. the part where you allready send the file and also name the library you are using. In the end, you should look up how to attach a file with that lib as something, that easily transfers from `byte[]` - e.g. an `InputStream` via `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Comment: btw, there is a mistake in line where you decode the content. better to write it like this: `byte[] pdfFileData = content.decodeBase64()`